# Local date time in certain format yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS

Tags: java-8, spring-data-jpa, localdate, zoneddatetime

I am trying to get LocalDateTime in certain format for my spring data jpa entity column.

I am not getting last 3 digits of millis/micros. I am not sure exactly what to call it.

I am always getting 000  for last 3 SSS portion even If I format

```
final String YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS_SSSSSS = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS";
    ZonedDateTime zdtAtUtc = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    LocalDateTime ldt = zdtAtUtc.toLocalDateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter destFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS_SSSSSS);

    System.out.println(zdtAtUtc);
    System.out.println(zdtAtUtc.format(destFormatter));
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

## Output

```
2019-07-30T15:23:18.232Z[UTC]
2019-07-30-15.23.18.232000
2019-07-30T15:23:18.232
```

Comment: Are you sure they exist? When I run your code with a debugger, the seconds only has 3 places, IE

time = {LocalTime@784} "15:34:18.068"
 hour = 15
 minute = 34
 second = 18
 nano = 68000000

Comment: From another application I am passing a string w/ yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS even last 3 digits of SSS have values. I am able to convert that particular string to LocalDateTime in desired format. It does have values. I am trying to get something similar for current date in UTC for that format

Comment: This is not possible with Java8, use java9 or later. Check out this answer for more details.

Comment: This sounds wrong: *LocalDateTime in certain format for my spring data jpa entity column*. For persistence you should not use `LocalDateTime` for a point in time but rather `Instant`. And you shouldn’t worry about the format.

Answer (score 3):

This is clock precision in Java 8.

If you'll check the code of now() method, it use behind an instant obtained like this:
    `Instant now = clock.instant();`

In Java 8 output for this instant:
    `2019-08-02T20:44:35.722Z`

In later versions:
    `2019-08-02T20:39:27.343408800Z`

So if you need more precision, you need to switch to a newer version of java.